# How to use Google's reCAPTCHA in an electron app?

Tags: electron, recaptcha, electron-builder

Google's reCAPTCHA is domain specific so when used in an Github's electron app, it gives the following error `ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key`.

Possibly because in an electron app the files are loaded with `file:///` protocol and hence no referer header is sent when the captcha is loaded. I am using `electron ./` to run the application.

Is there any solution for loading reCAPTCHA in an electron app?

Comment: You can disable the domain validation in the recaptcha configuration, and then it will load without problems. However, when you try to validate the recaptcha, it will get a different error: recaptcha__es.js:338 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

Comment: @AlvaroLuisBustamante are you sure that disabling "domain validation" will resolve the problem? For me it didn't make any difference!
BTW, I'm using recaptcha with cordova. It also uses file:/// protocol

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, like said user9699066, I had to use an express server since it's not working using `file://` protocol.

Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

server.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
const infos = server.listen(0, 'localhost', () => win.loadURL(`http://localhost:${infos.address().port}/dist/index.html`));
```

Then reCaptcha is working well.

Comment: I have tried this way but not working the solution

Answer (score -2):

Use express to host a local server and in the main.js edit the `loadUrl(__dirname + 'index.html')`function to `loadUrl('http://localhost:' + myLocalServerPort)`